# Case in protected switch

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When converting a project to use ARC what does “switch case is in protected scope” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562199/when-converting-a-project-to-use-arc-what-does-switch-case-is-in-protected-scop)

Got the following xcode:
But when i try to put something in case 1 (or empty) it's giving me an error?

Weird problem because i dont know what a protected switch is and how i should fix it. Does anyone has a solution or clue to fix this? Weird..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController *controller;

    switch(indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"0");

            //create instance of EKEventStore
            EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

            //creating instance of EKEvent
            EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

            //setting the appropriate properties of the new event
            event.title     = @"Woow";

            //event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];



            NSDateComponents *myDate2 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
            [myDate2 setDay:13];
            [myDate2 setMonth:12];
            [myDate2 setYear:2011];
            [myDate2 setHour:00];
            [myDate2 setMinute:34];

            event.startDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:myDate2];

            event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:3600 sinceDate:event.startDate];
            event.location = @"game2";
            event.notes = @" game";

            event.alarms = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:event.startDate]];

            [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
            NSError *error;
            [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];

            break;

        case 1:
            NSLog(@"1");    






            break;






    }

    {



        self.EKController.title = [self.EKList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];






    }

}


@end
```

But an error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 201, accepted):

You should wrap each switch statement with `{}` braces. For example:

```
switch (someInt) {
    case 0:
    {
        NSLog(@"Case 0");
    }
    break;
    case 1:
    {
        NSLog(@"Case 1");
    }
    break;
}
```

This has been answered already here by the way - [When converting a project to use ARC what does "switch case is in protected scope" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562199/when-converting-a-project-to-use-arc-what-does-switch-case-is-in-protected-scop)

Comment: It is not necessary to wrap EVERY switch in`{}`, only those that declare variables (explicitly or via a macro or compiler swizzle).  ARC has relatively little to do with it.

Answer (score 34):

In general, you should never declare variables inside a `case` body, unless you wrap the case body in `{}`.  Most C compilers will flag that as an error under several circumstances (though often a very obscure-sounding error).

The reason for this is that the compiler can't tell where the scope of the variable ends, and if you have a declaration in the first `case` body then it looks like the second `case` is a branch into the middle of the variable's scope, making the compiler wonder how/if it should be initialized.