# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on a UIActionSheet with ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

Just converted a project to ARC and am now getting a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS after I dismiss a UIActionsheet, it was previously working and I am unsure if this is even ARC related.  Zombies is enabled but showing me nothing and I tried instuments and it also gave me nothing.

This is presented in a modal view controller, case 0, the quit button works fine but the other two give me the bad access error.

This is my first conversion to ARC, am I missing something here?

Action sheet Creation:

```
-(IBAction)quitPressed:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit This Game?"    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Keep Playing" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Quit" otherButtonTitles:@"Quit and Reveal Answers",nil];
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
```

}

Action sheet delegate:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:  //quit
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
            [self.delegate quitGame];
        }];
        break;
        case 1:  //quit and reveal
            NSLog(@"reveal");
            break;
        case 2: //cancel
            NSLog(@"cancel"); 
            break;
        default:
        break;
    }
```

}

Comment: Which line is it crashing on?

Comment: put a breakpoint in the delegate method and report where it crashes

Comment: the closing brace of the switch stament.

Comment: Is your delegate a `strong` property?

Comment: Adam, you mean the UIActionSheetDelegate? The delegate is the view controller I presented the action sheet in and it's not declared as a property anywhere.  It's presented by a story board, I'll have to look into it further.

Comment: @tassinari No, I mean the `self.delegate` with `quitGame` method.

Comment: ok it's `@property (unsafe_unretained,nonatomic) id delegate;` Put that way via the ARC conversion tool

Comment: Change it to (strong, nonatomic) and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help.  I found the problem when I ran the project under xcode 4.5.  It gave a compile error: `switch case is protected in scope`

I wasn't getting that error in xcode 4.3

It was solved in this thread [When converting a project to use ARC what does "switch case is in protected scope" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562199/when-converting-a-project-to-use-arc-what-does-switch-case-is-in-protected-scop)

I wrapped each case in curly brackets and the problem has been fixed.

Comment: Ah. Xcode 4.3's ARC wasn't very mature yet. If you plan on going back, that's probably something you should mention in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

If your `delegate` is declared `strong` in the **.h** file. Have you initialized the `self.delegate` at least once in the **.m** file(preferably `viewDidLoad`) using

`self.delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

Answer (score 0):

Delegates should be `weak` or `assign` (`__weak` / `__unsafe_unretained` for ivars) to avoid any retain cycles.

Hold a reference to the sheet that you create. You can clear that reference once the sheet was closed.